# Git clone with --shared parameter

Tags: git, github

During work with repositories on my local machine, I need to clone them from one folder to another. When I need bare repo I use

```
git clone --bare --shared /path/to/repo
```

And I get bare repo without objects. It reduces my disk storage and execution time. But for some process with repo (e.g. merge two branches) bare repo is not suitable. And then I try

```
git clone --shared /path/to/repo
```

but in this command parameter "shared" does not change anything. How I can clone repo and reduce my disk storage?

Comment: What does "does not change anything" mean? What you're describing works exactly and as gratifyingly as I think you expect it to for me, so there's something missing from my understanding here.

Comment: @jthill, I think I understand where my problem. I execute `git count-objects -vH` and it seems that all work fine. I expected that my work folder is empty. But it looks like that work directory should not be empty